# What are the differences between .cpt templates and .pt templates?

Tags: plone, zope, zpt

What are the differences between .cpt templates and .pt templates in Plone? Are there any?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.cpt` files are controller page templates, `.pt` files are regular page templates.

The former are handled by the [Formcontroller tool](http://plone.org/products/cmfformcontroller), the latter are just normal page templates. The CMFFormController framework has largely been deprecated, and is in the process of being removed from Plone.

The best documentation about how these work that I can still find is this [2004 Plone conference presentation](http://plone.org/events/conferences/vienna-2004/handouts/FormControllerTutorial.pdf) (PDF).